# How to get values in a dataframe from data from another dataframe and generate new variable? And searches with dates and conditions in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 files: a)  I want to find values in one dataframe (A) from data in another dataframe (B), after that b) I need to get column (r1) of B when "a)" is True.  Besides, I need to gen a new variable like price2 = (price1/r1)*100.

And also, I have a Column 'date1' which has values in the form YYYYMM, The Column date1 is of type object.

```
df0["date1"] = pd.to_datetime(df0["date1"], format='%Y%m').dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
```

I wish to convert it in to date type.
These files are prepared to show as an example. But this I need to do with files 9 million records and monthly data of 30 years, it is an unbalanced data panel. And my idea is to migrate to python, pandas and I don't know much about both.

View of the dataframes (A) and (B). and the desired finished product data frame:

[Dataframe (A)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POD1V.png)

[DataFrame (B)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDU1U.png)

[finished product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7802N.png)

Files:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h4oqGykgkxC7UFnzyeixpxDTnh8Dpakd/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zaQ4nA8QSl40SMrkbdUKMp74pMIvZbp4/view?usp=sharing

file (link) with the desired finished product:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aXbSQ3JhLieLGRa7tHbuv9C52aNgG998/view?usp=sharing

I hope that somebudy will be able to help me please.

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
merged_df = df0.merge(df1, how='left', left_on='date1', right_on='date2')
merged_df['price2'] = merged_df['price1'] / merged_df['r1'] * 100
```

Comment: Hi Jeril. Thank you very much for very fast response and immense help. The first line works fine. But the second throws an error.
On the other hand, how can you convert or generate a new variable with date format for example date3 with YYYYMM format?

Comment: Hi Jeril.  Thank you so much again. The second sentence is ok. The problem was the format of the variable r1. a million of thanks.  But again .... how can you convert or generate a new variable with date format for example date3 with YYYYMM format?

Answer (score 0):

The code format it was:

```
dfr_1['r1'] = (dfr_1['r1'].replace('\.','', regex=True)
                    .replace(',','.', regex=True)
                    .astype(float))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ8IA.png)

```
merged_df = df0.merge(dfr_1, how='left', left_on='date1', right_on='date2')
merged_df["price1"] = merged_df["price1"].astype(str).astype(float)
merged_df['price2'] = merged_df['price1'] / merged_df['r1'] * 100
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXJiv.png)